# Is a Mode S address changed when an aircraft is sold to another country?

Tags: transponder, mode-s

The 24 bit Mode S address is issued by the national CAA where the aircraft is registered.

If it is sold to another country, with another CAA, is the Mode S address maintained or is a new one assigned?

Answer (score 6):

A **new Mode S address** will have to be assigned by the new authority:

> Aircraft addresses will be assigned in keeping with the following principles:
>
> - [...] when an aircraft changes its State of Registry, the previously assigned
>   address shall be relinquished and the new registering authority shall assign it
>   a new address; [...]

<sup>([ICAO - Guidelines and considerations for standaradised registration of aircraft with Mode S transponders](https://www.icao.int/SAM/Documents/GREPECAS/2008/CNSCOMM06/CNSC06WP12.pdf))</sup>

Until the new authority has assigned a new address, ICAO may assign a temporary address to the aircraft:

> Temporary addresses will be assigned to aircraft in special circumstances when operators
> have been unable to obtain an address from their States of Registry or private common
> mark registering authorities on a timely basis. ICAO will assign temporary addresses
> from the ICAO block shown in the appendix to this paper [...]

<sup>([ICAO - Guidelines and considerations for standaradised registration of aircraft with Mode S transponders](https://www.icao.int/SAM/Documents/GREPECAS/2008/CNSCOMM06/CNSC06WP12.pdf))</sup>